# set focus on input and change li background color

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, focus

This function allows me to create new li elements and append it to my current todo list.

```js
var newListElement =
  "<li>" +
  '<input type="checkbox"/>' +
  "<label>" +
  '<input [type="text"] placeholder="Insert your new task here"/>' +
  "</label>" +
  '<div class="arrow-btn"></div>' +
  "</li>";

$("ul.todo-list").append(newListElement);
```

In this function I want to set the cursor to my input text field and want to change the background of the li element to grey when it is newly created. But whenever I am creating a new li element the color of the li element is not going to change nor can't i set the cursor automatically to the input field. Only if I am clicking manually with my mouse in the newly created input field on the li element the background of the li element is changing.

```js
  
//change last added list element to grey
$('input:text').focus(function () {
   setEditModeItem($(this).closest('ul.todo-list > li'));
});
```

My question is there a way to set the focus dynamically to a input field and check if it has focus?

Comment: I believe you need to use Event Delegation, so use this `$('ul.todo-list').on("focus","input:text",function () {`

Comment: as @CarstenLøvboAndersen said you must use Event Delegation since you're adding the li from javascript the focus event won't be triggered. But, it will if you do as he said

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger focus in jQuery by calling [`.focus()`](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) method on the selected element, I added CSS background red to highlight the input on focus, note that you can use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to concatenate string, here is a working snippet:

```js
var newListElement = `<li>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <label>
  <input [type="text"] placeholder="Insert your new task here"/>
  </label>
  <div class="arrow-btn"></div>
  </li>`;

$("ul.todo-list").append(newListElement);
// this is how to trigger focus on input:
$("ul.todo-list li:last-child").find("input").focus();
//change last added list element to grey
$("input:text").focus(function () {
  //setEditModeItem($(this).closest('ul.todo-list > li'));
});
```

```css
ul.todo-list input:focus {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="todo-list"></ul>
```